# Why would the spark executor runs out of memory when multiple tasks are executed serially?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Please see the update for the follow up.

Please note I am not interested in increasing the parallelism of this process.  I am trying to **understand the executor memory model**.

Let's say my application is decomposed to 1 stage (several mappers, filter, store result to hdfs *[in other words, no reducers]*)

Let's say I have:

- 10 Executors (1 core per Executor, 5 GB per executor)
- 10 Partitions
- 10 Tasks (I know that each task requires 5 GB to complete successfully)

I end up with 10 tasks, each task running on an executor successfully.

Now same application and same setup but this time I have reduced the number of executors:

- 5 Executors (1 core per Executor, 5 GB per executor)
- 10 Partitions
- 10 Tasks (I know that each task requires 5 GB to complete successfully)

I still have 10 tasks.  But this time the 5 executors, execute 5 tasks in parallel successfully. But when the executor tries to execute the second set of tasks (tasks 6-10) the executor tries to get more than the specified amount of memory and yarn kills it...

I thought what should happen is that 5 tasks would run successfully then 5 more tasks would run successfully.  Since all tasks are identical...

But it looks like the executor is forced to carry some memory footprint from the execution of the first 5 tasks.

---

**Follow up**

The reason the executors were failing was because I was doing a lot of string manipulation and a configured `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to be too small (512 MB).

Once I fixed this problem, I repeated the experiment and was able to successfully process the 10 tasks using 5 executors.

I am leaving this question and the findings here as documentation, in case someone has the same question...